# Re-arrange bar chart in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I got a bar chart and I need to re-order the bars show in it. The bars show at which speed a person was driving and are currently sorted by the one that appears most often.

[image]

The data is imported in the structure:

[image]

The fields named `*_id` are used for filtering. What is shown in the bars is the count of the `gemeten_snelheid` column.

As shown in the bar chart the speeds are not sorted by "speed" but by count. Is it possible to re-order the bars so they are arranged by speed, and how would this be done?

I don't really know how to create a working example of this as the data is imported from a database connection, so if any more information is required feel free to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a new column and order by it, you could do it in sql, for example:

```
case when column1<30 then 1
     when column1<40 then 2
     when column1<50 then 3
 column1_sort
```

Or you can do it in PowerBI, you could *Add Column* -> *Conditional Column* and write your Ifs. Or you can when in PowerBI desktop *right click table, select New column* and write something like:

```
Column_sort = if([Column1]="<30",1,if([Column1]="<40",2,if([Column1]="<50",3,4)))
```

Then select your not sorted column (Column1) and under *Column tools* there is *Sort by column*, and from there select column1_sort

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this below option? Here I am getting your expected output-

[image]